# Not giving output When running LocalScript inside of StarterGui

Tags: lua, roblox

So, Im tring to make a Mind Control script inside of Roblox. Im using the local script so i can use the UserInputServer Module. But When I Run It(Its inside of StartGui), I doesn't give any output. Here is the source:

```
--Made By BioShot!--

local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local Enabled = false
local Active = false
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    print("Player Added!")
    UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
        if(input['KeyCode'] == Enum['KeyCode']["E"]) then
            if(Enabled == true) then
                --Rase Player/Dummy/NPC
                local Mouse = plr:GetMouse()
                Active = true
                while(Active == true) do
                    local Enemy = Mouse["Target"]
                    print(Enemy)
                    Enemy.CFrame = Enemy.CFrame + CFrame.new(0,1,0)
                    wait(0.5)
                end
            else
                --Drop Player/Dummy/NPC
            end
        end
    end)
    UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
        if(input['KeyCode'] == Enum["KeyCode"]["F"]) then
            Enabled = true
            print("Enabled.")
        end
        if(input['KeyCode'] == Enum["KeyCode"]["E"]) then
            Active = false
        end
    end)
end)
```

Comment: What do you mean by output? What are you trying to achieve? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Well, What I have print statements inside of the script and when I ran the game, It didn't show me anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements are only printed after `game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)` detects a player being added. Due to the code running in a LocalScript, the player will have already been added by the time the script starts waiting for players. If a second player joins the game, "Player Added!" will indeed be printed in the first player's console.

The player can instead be indexed by using `local plr = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer`.

The script still errors when the player's mouse is pointing to nothing and when trying to change the Enemy's position, but these can be easily fixed. The script then lifts objects upwards by hovering over them and pressing E.

Final code:

```
--Made By BioShot!--

local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local Enabled = false
local Active = false
local plr = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer

print("Player Added!")
UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)
    if(input['KeyCode'] == Enum['KeyCode']["E"]) then
        if(Enabled == true) then
            --Rase Player/Dummy/NPC
            local Mouse = plr:GetMouse()
            Active = true
            while(Active == true) do
                local Enemy = Mouse["Target"]
                if Enemy then --Make sure the player's mouse isn't pointing to nothing
                    print(Enemy)
                    Enemy.CFrame += Vector3.new(0,1,0)
                end
                task.wait(0.5) --More accurate than wait(0.5)
            end
        else
            --Drop Player/Dummy/NPC
        end
    end
end)
UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(input)
    if(input['KeyCode'] == Enum["KeyCode"]["F"]) then
        Enabled = true
        print("Enabled.")
    end
    if(input['KeyCode'] == Enum["KeyCode"]["E"]) then
        Active = false
    end
end)
```